# External monitor options /availability for a 2010 MacBook Pro

Tags: monitors

I’ve been charged with finding an external monitor (wall mount) 32”, for a friend’s 2010 MacBook Pro. I’ve no idea where to start.

Regarding connectivity (she says no WiFi and/or no Bluetooth). 
Doesn’t an external monitor or tv typically require an HDMI cable? I don’t believe the 2010 15” laptop even has that port, and her laptop is in the shop, she knows even less than me and I’ve been unable to that information online so far.

Her price point is max 500.
I’m at a loss as to where to begin. Any help on what questions I need to ask, where to look, and dare to dream, suggestions on what to buy would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is landspace vs portrait mode a concern for 32”? Also, might be better for her to find out if she at least has a HDMI or DVI port, or some port?

Comment: Even if she has a Mini DisplayPort, which most 2010 MacBook Pro had, she can buy a DisplayPort to Mini DisplayPort converter. Best to wait until the laptop comes back from the shop.